# Morphia: How to i match a 2 level nested document in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, morphia

I have a collection in which documents look like this:

```
 /* 1 */
{
    "_id" : "U1234",
    "person" : {
        "address" : {
            "city" : "X"
        }
    }
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : "U1235",
    "person" : {
        "address" : {
            "city" : "Y"
        }
    }
}
```

The below raw shell query works fine, but cannot convert it to **morphia** code:

```
db.getCollection('bypass').aggregate([
{$match:{"person.address.city": "X"}}
])
```

How do I write a morphia aggregate query to count the cities with X value assuming that I have an index on **city** field?

I tried

```
query.field("person.address.city", "X");
```

OR

```
AggregationPipeline aggregationPipeline = datastore.createAggregation(Session.class)
                    .project(Projection.projection("cityFound", "person.address.city"))
                    .match(query.field("cityFound").equal("X"));
```

Unfortunately, both doesn't work. What am I doing wrong here? I am using **Morphia v1.2.1**

Comment: Did you try: `datastore.createAggregation(Session.class).match(query.field("person.address.city").equal("X"))`?

Comment: Yes tried. Got this error: org.mongodb.morphia.query.ValidationException: The field 'address' could not be found in 'com.mongodb.DBObject' while validating - person.address.city; if you wish to continue please disable validation.

Comment: I would recommend trying a newer version (I just released 1.6.0 and 2.0.0 today!)  Lots of bug fixes have happened since 1.2.1 and in 2.0.0 there's a complete reimplementation of the aggregation API that is much more robust and complete.

Comment: @evanchooly: Thanks. I need to quickly implement this filter. I have created index on this city field and have millions of records in my db. Is there a way to put this in match query? That would allow me filter out a lot of documents. Can you share a sample query please?

Comment: I missed this comment, sorry.  if you're still working this, it would be helpful to see the model classes.  That path should work but it depends on how you modeled your entities.